# Python - Having trouble creating a dictionary from a JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary, tweepy

I'm trying to take the JSON from a twitter get_user query and turn it into a Python object that I can extract data from (twitter handle, location, screen name, etc.)

Here is what I created. I am not sure why it doesn't work.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth,parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())

user = api.search_users('google.com')

t_dict = json.loads(user)

pprint(t_dict)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Get_User_By_URL.py", line 23, in <module>
    t_dict = json.loads(user)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: json.loads only takes string as argument. Is user really a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api.search_users` is already returning a python object. It isn't a json string that needs to be parsed. According to [tweetpy documentation](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/api.html#API.search_users) `search_users` actually returns a list of users. So the following is possible:

```
for user in api.search_users('google.com'):
    print user.screen_name
```

Comment: Thanks. How come when I do user = api.search_users('google.com'). "Print user" returns an extremely long JSON page? Does it just select the first in the list? I am trying to query for the URL for google's homepage WITHIN the profile description.

Comment: It looks like a string, but it's a python dictionary or sth. print type(user) to find exact type.